# Add an item to ListBox and get the ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

***UPDATE:***

I uploaded a demo trying to explain my problem clear. Download it [here](https://www.box.com/s/5gltokm5wreara2xg19k).

I'm developing an manager class that deals with the selection of ListBox. (The default selection function provided by ListBox cannot satisfy me requirements)

So, **when an item is added to the ListBox, my manager class should get the corresponding ListBoxItem** and make it selected or unselected.

Although I think **`ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged` should tell some information of the newly added item, it provides same event arg when `ListBox.Items.Add` is called multiple times(with different parameter)**, which confuses me a lot. Can anyone tell me how to get the newly generated ListBoxItem for the newly added item.

Code to demonstrate the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add two items" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <ListBox Name="listBox">
            <System:Int32>1</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>2</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>3</System:Int32>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SelectionManager selectionManager = new SelectionManager();
        selectionManager.Join(listBox);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(4);
        listBox.Items.Add(5);
    }
}
```

Here, in Button_Click, two items are added to the listBox, and selectionManager should get the ListBoxItem at same time.

```
class SelectionManager
{
    public void Join(ListBox element)
    {
        element.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
    }

    private List<int> listBoxItemPendingJoinIndexes = new List<int>();

    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Contract.Requires(listBoxItemPendingJoinIndexes.Count > 0);
        ItemContainerGenerator generator = (ItemContainerGenerator)sender;
        if (generator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            return;
        generator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;

        foreach (var index in listBoxItemPendingJoinIndexes)
        {
            ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)generator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            Join(listBoxItem);
        }
        listBoxItemPendingJoinIndexes.Clear();
    }

    void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemContainerGenerator generator = (ItemContainerGenerator)sender;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                listBoxItemPendingJoinIndexes.Add(e.Position.Index
                      + e.Position.Offset);//same e.Position
                generator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code or something?

Comment: @Soner Yes, I updated. Please check.

Comment: Does you comment "same e.Position" also mean "same e.Offset"? Maybe [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/13/implementing-a-virtualizingpanel-part-2-iitemcontainergenerator.aspx) is helpful. And are you really attaching a `StatusChanged` handler on every `Add`? And what does `Join(listBoxItem)` do?

Comment: @Clemens e.Position.Index and e.Position.Offset both are same. I know adding an item doesn't mean creating an ListBoxItem, so I subscribe ItemsChanged, hoping to get some information of the new item, and in StatusChanged event, use the information from ItemsChanged to retrieve the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

If your items source is an `ObservableCollection`, you can use [`OnCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654934.aspx) event, which has a [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx) Check `NewItems` for the list of new items involved in the change.

Comment: I uploaded a demo trying to explain my problem clear. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a cutsom listbox class and override the methods?

```
 public class SafeListBox : ListBox 
    { 
        delegate void insertDelegate(int i, object o); 

        public SafeListBox() 
        { 
            this.Items = new CustomObjectCollection(this); 
        } 

        public new CustomObjectCollection Items 
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        } 

        public class CustomObjectCollection : ListBox.ObjectCollection 
        { 
            private ListBox listBox = null; 

            public CustomObjectCollection(ListBox listBox) : base(listBox) 
            { 
                this.listBox = listBox; 
            } 

            public new void Insert(int index, object item) 
            { 
                if (listBox.InvokeRequired) 
                { 
                    insertDelegate setTextDel = delegate(int i, object o) 
                    { 
                        base.Insert(i, o); 
                    }; 

                    try 
                    { 
                        listBox.Invoke(setTextDel, new object[] { index, item }); 
                    } 
                    catch 
                    { 
                    } 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    base.Insert(index,item); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: @NorbertPisz How do you actually get a generated `ListBoxItem` from an item object (e.g. a `string`) as asked for in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i fully understand the question. But if it is only about how to manipulate a newly created ListBoxItem *once* before it is displayed, you could create a derived ListBox and just override the [PrepareContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) method.

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        var listBoxItem = element as ListBoxItem;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I uploaded a demo trying to explain my problem clear. See my update.